# json values in variable for D3 chart throwing error.While the static json files works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

We are trying to fetch the json values from a variable(data) and giving this to D3 as input in the form of json. But it is throwing error in firebug saying "data.links is not defined".
This chart is coming fine if we take the json values from sample.json file with d3.json() function, but not with the variable.

below is the sample json,

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "group": "pepsi",
        "name": "solly",
        "size": 20
    },
    {
        "group": "coke",
        "name": "ROBdey",
        "size": 7
    },
    {
        "group": "limca",
        "name": "Mike",
        "size": 5
    },
    {
        "group": "coke",
        "name": "OFFA",
        "size": 1
    },
    {
        "group": "limca",
        "name": "deuje",
        "size": 1
    },
    {
        "group": "pepsi",
        "name": "EITAKdell",
        "size": 1
    },
    {
        "group": "coke",
        "name": "COOK",
        "size": 1
    },
    {
        "group": "pepsi",
        "name": "CRISLY",
        "size": 1
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 3,
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "source": 4,
        "target": 4,
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "source": 7,
        "target": 57,
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "source": 10,
        "target": 10,
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "source": 12,
        "target": 332,
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "source": 14,
        "target": 325,
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "source": 17,
        "target": 548,
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "source": 19,
        "target": 157,
        "value": 1
    }
]
}
```

and D3 code is here

we are trying to retriev the data from rest api call with mongoDB with jquery.This we are using becasue the JSON format returned from mongoDB is not refined.

Comment: Can you cross-check whether you are getting proper json data from call. If yes, is it in the right format?

Answer (score 1):

According to the code pasted with pastebin, here's how dummy function looks like:

```
function dummy() {
    var form_data = {
        user: "example.com/foo",
        is_ajax: 1
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: form_data.user,
        contentType: "application/jsonp",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var t = data.rows[0];
            delete t["_id"];
            markers = JSON.stringify(t);
        }

    });
    return markers;
}
```

It didn't work because it's impossible to return a value from an asynchronous call like that. `markers` is undefined when you are trying to return it.

**Edit:**

As moonwave99 pointed out, you should process your data *inside* success callback:

```
function dummy() {
    var form_data = {
        user: "example.com/foo",
        is_ajax: 1
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: form_data.user,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var t = data.rows[0];
            delete t["_id"];
            markers = JSON.stringify(t);

            processMarkers(markers);
        }

    });
}
```

You should move most of the global scoped code to the `processMarkers` functions. Also, `dummy` is no longer a great name for such a function.

Comment: That won't work either - you have to do your business _into_ the callback.